# Highcharts : compare current value/previous value to get the rate

Tags: highcharts

let me know how to get the difference between my current value "this.y.toLocalString()" and the previous value ? I would like to know the rate of change between this 2 values.

```
var x = document.getElementById("people2").selectedIndex;
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[x].id;

 //Charts       
    var db = data.dataevolution[x]

         $('#container').highcharts({
            chart:{
                type:'column',
            },

            xAxis:{
                categories: [
                    '2005','2006','2007','2008',
                ]
            },

            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Nombre'
                        },

                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                    return this.value.toLocaleString();
                         }
                        }
                    },
            tooltip: {
                 formatter: function() {
                 return 'Le nombre de <b>' + this.series.name + '</b> est de <b>' + this.y.toLocaleString() + '</b>, en '+ this.x +'<br>soit une évolution de '     ; }
                    },

            series: [

        {
                name: [db.metier],
                data: [db.annee2005,db.annee2006,db.annee2007,db.annee2008]

            },  
            ]
        });
```

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: It's a chart column. Il would like to have in the tooltip : the value "this.y" and the previous value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the prevous point like:

```
tooltip: {
   formatter: function() {
         var prevPoint = this.point.x == 0 ? null : this.series.data[this.point.x - 1];
         // do stuff with it
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/c98vd98b/).